# Using numpy to make an average over multiple files

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I am pretty new to Python and want to use `numpy` to make an average over multiple files. I have seen some similar questions but I am not familiar enough with python yet to use it for my goal.

The Situation:

I have a loop which creates in each step 101 `.dat` files. Those files contain similar content like this:

```
" #t  
-0.00219801    
0.0174122  
0.0220081  
0.0166335  
-0.02764  
-0.0343197  
0.0495079  
0.0355671  
0.00123321  
-0.0785652 "
```

the name of the .dat files has the following structure with i being the number of the step in the loop: `i_00000` - `i_00100`. Now, I want to read in the files as arrays in `numpy` and make average over files `i_00000` to `i+100_00000` (the same with `i_00001` and so on) get again 101 `.dat` files each with 10 values.

Sorry for this very newby question but I am kinda stucked at the moment.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I get this right you have 101 steps with 101 .dat files each ranging from 0_00000.dat to 100_00100.dat and you want to calculate the average of each row for each of the 101 .dat files in each step, resulting in 101 .dat files with 10 lines each containing the averages of the respective rows of all .dat files for the given step.

The following code reads all .dat files for a given step into one large numpy array, calculates the average for each row and stores the result in a .dat file with name "average_i.dat" where i is the step number.

```
import numpy as np
import glob

## iterate over all 101 steps
for i in range(101):

    ## get list of .dat files for each step
    files = glob.glob("%d_*.dat" % i)

    ## read contents of all files into one numpy array
    ## this generates a 100x10 array for 100 files with 10 lines each
    x = np.array([np.genfromtxt(f) for f in files])

    ## calculate average of each row
    m = np.mean(x, axis=0)

    ## store averages into new .dat file
    np.savetxt("average_%03d.dat" % i, m)
```

Comment: thanks but I get a runtime error: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:59: RuntimeWarning: Mean of empty slice.
  warnings.warn("Mean of empty slice.", RuntimeWarning)
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:70: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  ret = ret.dtype.type(ret / rcount)

Comment: This happens when glob does not find any matching files so "files" is just an empty list. Please check if the glob pattern actually matches your file names and adjust the path if your files are located in a different path.

Comment: my file names are "vel_x_y.dat" x in range (100-199) and y in range (00000-00100). Is "glob" simply able to find all matching files or do I have to use two variables to complete the file name?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: ok I think solved the glob problem. Now I have a new error. "File "./average_sim.py", line 22, in <module>
    m = np.mean(x, axis=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 2885, in mean
    out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 65, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

sorry it's my first numpy code I need as much guidance as possible :D

Comment: The numpy array generated seems to be not a float64 ndarray. Given your file format np.recfromcsv may be inappropriate. Please replace the call by np.genfromtxt and try again.